# Custom shortcut for switching keyboard input languages in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

I'm using Linux for years and now I have to work with Windows XP at work. The problem is I don't like default shortcuts for switching keyboard input languages: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. And I'd really like to change the shortcut to the one I'm using in Linux <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.
I've googled for a while, played with registry but have not found any solution.
So, can I assign custom (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>) shortcut for switching keyboard input languages?

Thanks in advance,
Andriy

Answer (score 2):

You could use AutoHotKey!

```
LShift::
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 500)
{
    Send ^{LShift}
}
else
    Send {LShift}
return
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the fact that you can change the language by pressing Ctrl+Shift/Alt+Shift, which is pretty normal to press accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, you can choose to have the grave/backtick key (`) be the key that switches keyboard layouts. However, you then have to come up with an alternative way of inserting the grave/backtick character if you ever want to use it (as programmers sometimes do). Furthermore, if you're using the Sticky Keys feature, you also need an alternative way to type in a tilde (~), which is normally selected by pressing the Shift key plus the grave/backtick key. One way that I've found is to use the Windows key plus period, which brings up a dialog that shows emoji but also lets you choose symbols. It so happens that the first element in the 13th row is an ASCII grave/backtick, and the third element in the 14th row is an ASCII tilde. Microsoft does not arrange the symbols in a logical order (for instance, ASCII first), nor does it even let you see the Unicode code points when you hover over the symbols. Thus, I needed to figure this out via experimentation.