# Switch keyboard layout with "Windows" keys in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, input-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom shortcut for switching keyboard input languages in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/125655/custom-shortcut-for-switching-keyboard-input-languages-in-windows-xp)

I use two keyboard layouts in my system - Russian and English. Windows 7 offers only two ways to switch between layouts with a keyboard - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. I find both inconvenient.

I am used to Ubuntu and I want to have this:

1. When I press left <kbd>[image: Windows key]</kbd> key - English layout is turned on
2. When I press right <kbd>[image: Windows key]</kbd> key - Russian layout is turned on

Obviously, default <kbd>[image: Windows key]</kbd> key behaviour will be overridden. Is there any software that can do this?

Comment: You need an AutoHotKey script for this.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe, although the resource linked to may work, this post clearly states Windows 7!

Comment: @DaveRook: I'm pretty sure there's no new in-built way to do this in Win7 that wasn't there in XP, so despite the Windows version specified the solution remains the same. Do you know of any [OOTB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_feature) 1-to-many keyboard shortcut remap solution that's available in Win7 and not in XP? If yes, why didn't you flag to reopen?

Answer (score 1):

[Keymapper](https://code.google.com/p/keymapper/) will let you change keys, and it will completely override any defaults.

As it states on the web page, **Important note for Windows 7 Users**

> Windows 7 does not support per-user key mappings. Until the next release of Key Mapper, you will have to manually switch to 'Boot' mappings from the Mappings menu, reboot to change the mappings, and you will need to have Administrative access to your computer to set key mappings that will work in Windows 7.

---

To map multiple keypresses to a single key, [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) will give you the functions to remap almost anything - for instance, I map WIN+Z to log into an application I use frequently. Remapping the Windows Keys can be done with lines like `RWin::^Shift`

Comment: Are you ***sure*** this will work? If the program uses the **[Scancode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx) [Map](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/Q181348)** registry key (which it looks like it does, same as other apps such as [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com)), there's no way to map a single key (Windows, in this case) to multiple (Ctrl+Shift or Ctrl+Alt).

Comment: added info on another program that can capture key presses

Comment: +1 for the edit, AHK is probably the best way to do it as I had suggested above.